# Objective-C: Separate number right/left of decimal

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter, cgfloat

I am trying to separate the left and right numbers from a float so I can turn each into a string. So for example, **5.11**, I need to be able to turn **5** into a string, and **11** into another string.

```
// from float: 5.11
NSString * leftNumber  = @"5";
NSString * rightNumber = @"11";
```

From this, I can turn **5.11** into **5' 11"**.

Comment: You know, of course, that a decimal fraction does not "map" to feet/inches, but rather (for 2 digits) feet and hundredths.  And even if the value is valid feet/inches to start with, reading as a float and then "reconstituting" it as you're doing could cause rounding errors if you're not careful.

Comment: I know that a decimal number does not map into height measurements, thank you.

Comment: Do you understand the rounding problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

1. Use `stringWithFormat` to convert to string "5.11".
2. Use `componentsSeparatedByString` to seperate into an array of "5" and "11".
3. Combine with `stringWithFormat`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `NSString stringWithFormat` and math functions for that:

```
float n = 5.11;
NSString * leftNumber  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", truncf(n)];
NSString * rightNumber = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", fmodf(n, 1.0)] substringFromIndex:2];
NSLog(@"'%@' '%@'", leftNumber, rightNumber);
```

However, this is not ideal, especially for representing lengths in customary units, because 0.11 ft is *not* 11 inches. You would be better off representing the length as an integer in the smallest units that you support (say, for example, 1/16-th of an inch) and then convert it to the actual length for display purposes. In this representation 5 ft 11 in would be 5*12*16 + 11*16 = 1136.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a number formatter as such

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.decimalSeparator = @"'";
formatter.positiveSuffix = @"\"";
formatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = true;
NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(5.11)];

// Output : 5'11"
```